# Buffer audio livestream with ExoPlayer

Tags: java, android, buffer, live-streaming, exoplayer

I am using ExoPlayer on Android to play a radio audio livestream.
With the standard implementation the livestream stops playing immediately when network connection gets lost.

ExoPlayer State:
STARTED -> connection gets lost -> immediately BUFFERING -> after 2-3 sec. IDLE

Is it possible to buffer the radio livestream so if there is no internet connection that the stream continues playing for a few sekonds until the network connection is back.
The music app Tunein has this feature. Is this possible with ExoPlayer or how is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

For 2.x , Buffer size can be modified using `LoadControl`:

```
    DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl(allocator, 30000,
 45000, 1500, DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_AFTER_REBUFFER_MS);
```

[Official docs](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl.html)

Update:
But ExoPlayer has one issue:
[Audio stream moved to buffering state immediately on disconnection of internet](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1606) which is scheduled to be fixed by end of year (or shortly thereafter) as developer said

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. after connection gets lost the player state immediately is BUFFERING and after that IDLE

Comment: it is still not fixed... hopefully they will fix it soon. The TuneIn App has this feature and it works...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible now, use ExoPlayer 2.7.0 which has this functionality. Refer to this issue: [Seeking in radio streams](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4917)

in this last few comments in this post it is mentioned. Hope it helps.